# Some functions are declared with prototype but can not find definition in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am a newbie to Linux operating system and recently I was digging on the implementation details of uprobe. I encountered a macros `vma_interval_tree_foreach` which I searched it on https://elixir.bootlin.com/. It gives following definition:

```
#define vma_interval_tree_foreach(vma, root, start, last)       \
    for (vma = vma_interval_tree_iter_first(root, start, last); \
         vma; vma = vma_interval_tree_iter_next(vma, start, last))
```

So I tried to figure out what `vma_interval_tree_iter_first` does but unfortunately I can not find any definition of it. By quickly browsing through the Internet, I still could not find an answer. Does anyone know how to find the definition of it or some explanations of this wierd behavior? Thanks ~

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll up from [the `vma_interval_tree_foreach` declaration](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.11/source/include/linux/mm.h#L2555), there’s a comment which gives a hint:

```c
/* interval_tree.c */
```

There are two `interval_tree.c` files; the relevant one here is [`mm/interval_tree.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.11/source/mm/interval_tree.c), which [defines `vma_interval_tree`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.11/source/mm/interval_tree.c#L23):

```c
INTERVAL_TREE_DEFINE(struct vm_area_struct, shared.rb,
             unsigned long, shared.rb_subtree_last,
             vma_start_pgoff, vma_last_pgoff, /* empty */, vma_interval_tree)
```

This uses [the `INTERVAL_TREE_DEFINE` macro](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.11/source/include/linux/interval_tree_generic.h#L28) which produces the definitions of `vma_interval_tree_iter_first` and `vma_interval_tree_iter_next` along with a few other functions.

Comment: This really helps, thanks~